# How can I fix my delete key in VIM over ssh? (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vim, backspace

When I use VIM in the terminal on my local machine (Mac OS X Snow Leopard), the delete key is really backspace (i.e., destructive backspace).

When I SSH into a particular server, for some reason it's regular delete (i.e., delete the character under the cursor).

How can I change it to be consistent?  I've tried a dozen solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Checking the "Delete sends Ctrl-H" box in Terminal Preferences->Advanced doesn't work -- this is non-destructive backspace.

I've tried about a hundred different key mappings in VIM, to no avail.

Interestingly, the key works as expected when I'm typing commands in VIM (e.g., `: <something>`) -- it's only screwed up when I'm editing the actual text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me:

```
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

I'm not sure exactly what it does but it is listed as a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844611/1956030) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems). I found this line in a vimrc file distributed with Ubuntu where the behavior of the mac "delete" key (otherwise known as the "backspace" key) works as expected without any other configuration.

The behavior I was experiencing was a bell sound (no characters deleted) when pressing the mac "delete" key (otherwise known as the "backspace" key) in insert mode. I am using a compiled version of vim 7.3 on "amazon linux" over ssh from a mac. Pressing `<ctrl-v><delete>` when in insert mode resulted in ^?.

Answer (score 8):

Couple of ideas to try:

- In your `.vimrc` file on the remote server, add this line:

  ```
  set term=linux
  ```
- In your `.bash_profile` file (or whatever corresponds to your shell of choice) on the remote server:

  ```
  stty erase ^H
  ```

  Note:  to make this work correctly, you must type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> to type the `^H` character.

  Also, make sure "Delete sends Ctrl-H" is checked in your Terminal prefs.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
set <Del>=<C-v><Del>
```

to the vimrc on the target machine. Here you must type <kbd><C-v></kbd><kbd><Del></kbd> while being logged on the target machine. If this does not work, check `verbose imap <Del>`: this should tell you whether some plugin has remapped `<Del>` in insert mode.

Comment: Hi ZyX, tried this but no go. When I hit <Ctrl-v><Del> I end up with a command looking like ":set <Del>=^?". I entered it both at the command line in VIM and in my .vimrc; also tried setting <BS> in the same way, but nothing makes any difference at all. verbose imap <Del> and verbose imap <BS> both say "no mapping found." Very frustrating since, as I mentioned, the key works as it should (as destructive backspace) when I'm actually typing the VIIM command at the :prompt; just goes wrong in the actual document.

Comment: @Aeonaut Very strange since I can make `<F1>` work like `<Del>` with `set <Del>=<C-v><F1> <F1>=<C-v><F2>`. On all my terminals `<Del>` sends "^[[3~", but I saw terminals where it sends `^?`. What do you mean by «destructive backspace»? Maybe you should try `inoremap <Del> <Esc>cl` (I use this sequence for deleting previous character in transliteration plugin, it works regardless of `backspace` and `delcombine` options). Also try `:fixdel` command.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=295

> I fixed the problem by changing my Terminal.app settings. Under Terminal > Preferences choose Advanced. Check “Delete sends Ctrl-H”. Now, vi and vim should understand the delete key more intuitively.
>
> Note: Mapping the “delete” key in my vimrc file seemed like probably the correct way to do this, but that’s a lot of trouble. Is there any reason not to do it this way?