# Odd behavior of backspace in Vim (SSH to Linux from Mac)

Tags: vim, backspace

I didn't change any setting of my Vim, but today the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> gets some crazy behavior. Every time when I hit it, it does not delete a character, but prints `^?`. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: What OS? Whst do you have in your .vimrc (can you put it down somewhere?)

Comment: Try to remove all the plugins and `.vimrc` and then look again to Backspace behavior. Is it changed? If yes, then you can at least find the reason by method of exclusion.

Comment: @ldigas I login to Linux from a Mac via Terminal. `.vimrc` actually sources from a standard vimrc of my company. There is no recent change for this `.vimrc` source. @dimonomid Thank you! I just took it out. Still no luck. This may tell me that this problem may not come from the linux terminal.

Comment: Ok I logged to the Linux box directly and the vim worked just fine. That means the problem comes from the communication between the Mac and the Linux.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem comes from the communication between Mac Terminal the Linux Terminal.

Go to the Mac Terminal -> Preferences -> Advanced tab, check the option "Delete sends Ctrl-H". Then after I login to Linux, and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works just fine in Vim.

Comment: Awesome. Though I wonder why it works sometimes even this setting.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure why it would randomly start doing this based on the information you gave, but trying adding this line to your `.vimrc`

```
set backspace=start,eol,indent
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not work. :( Thank you though!

Comment: Are you using vim on a local machine or over a remote connection?

Comment: over a remote connection. Does it matter?

Comment: Try the suggestions in the `:fixdel` section of the vim docs: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:fixdel

Comment: I also tried this. This makes Backspace work like Delete, which is not what I want.

Comment: This worked for me.  I was having problems with backspace in vim when I was ssh'ing from mac to raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac Mavricks and Yosemite Open a terminal, then command+, for preferences, click on the profile tab, click on the -keyboard- menu, then add +

```
Key: very bottom, <= Delete
Modifier: ^ Control
Action: Send Text
Text: H
```

click Ok